# Programmatically switching to another tab does not change NavigationBar Title

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a TabBarController imbedded in a NavController. My TabBarController viewDidAppear method calls this method to set the navigationBar according to the TabBarItem.tag :

```
-(void)updateNaviationWithTabBarItem:(UITabBarItem *)item{
if(item.tag == 1){
    self.title = @"Live Feed";
    NSLog(@"live");
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor blackColor], NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:22]}];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:.4];
    [self.button  setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.41 green:0.68 blue:0.9 alpha:1]];
}else if (item.tag == 2){
    self.title = @"Camera";
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor], NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:22]}];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.41 green:0.68 blue:0.9 alpha:.4];
    [self.button  setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
}
```

After the user uploads a picture from the CameraViewController, the tab is programmatically changed like this:

```
-(void)presentFeedView {
FeedTableViewController *feedVC = self.tabBarController.viewControllers[0];
[self.tabBarController setSelectedViewController:feedVC];}
```

When I arrive at the tab the navigationBar retains the settings from the previous ViewController. This also happens in other tabs.

Should I be transitioning to the tab after checking for tabBarItem.tag?
Should I be calling this method from somewhere else?

EDIT: I can tell from the log statements that the method is being called once and only once when the view is initially loaded.

Comment: This may help you     self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"YOUR_Title_text";

Comment: why don't you debug your code and check that whether control is going in if block or else block...

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually change it in the view controller when you switch tabs.   Normally its in viewWillAppear, but I'm not sure if this fires when you switch your tabs, but this is the code you need to invoke.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    [self setTitle:@"A"];
    self.tabBarController.navigationItem.title = @"A";
}
```

You might need to put it down in here though.

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    //change the title based on viewController that is selected
    self.title = @"New title";
}
```

Comment: I should have mentioned. I have three VC that are a subclass of FeedViewController so I need to check the tab index or tag I think

Comment: Right, save the data and index it by controller id or something.   You could have each one implement the method so when it gets called they correctly display the right title.